# Do you need to ask for permission to use the microphone when running an app in simulator?

Tags: swift, avaudioplayer, avaudiorecorder

I Created a simple audio player/recorder player using AVAudioPlayer and AVAudioRecorder. The audio player works as expected but the audio recorder doesn't seem to record or playback the recording even though it builds successfully without any errors. Im wondering if it needs permission to the mic? I'm using version 11.X The code is below any help is much appreciated.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation //must import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    // create property called audioPlayer equal to player
    var audioPlayer : AVAudioPlayer?
    var audioRecorder : AVAudioRecorder?


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        //create the audio session
        let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

        //set category where we want it to happen (PlayAndRecord) try? = if it doesnt work then set it nil
        try? session.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playAndRecord)

        //play any audio through device speaker
        try? session.overrideOutputAudioPort(.speaker)

        // set the session to active, if it doesnt work se it to nil
        try? session.setActive(true)

        //setup the recording and settings to where audio will be saved (Document folder on device) and set the name and file type (iloveaudio.mp3)

        if let basePath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first {

            let paths = [basePath, "iloveaudioios.mp3"]
            if let audioURL = NSURL.fileURL(withPathComponents: paths) {

                //create a settings dictionary> orignally it's set to empty using ([:])
                var settings : [String : Any] = [:]
                //set the file type to mp3
                settings[AVFormatIDKey] = Int(kAudioFileMP3Type)
                //set the sample rate
                settings[AVSampleRateKey] = 44100.0
                //set number of channels
                settings[AVNumberOfChannelsKey] = 2
                // specify the path and settings using var and try to run the recorder if it faile set it to nil
             audioRecorder = try? AVAudioRecorder(url: audioURL, settings: settings)

                //prepare the recorder of ot fails set it to nil
                audioRecorder?.prepareToRecord()

            }
        }


        playerSetup(audioURL: nil)


                    }

     //which file to play if something is recorded
    func playerSetup(audioURL:URL?) {


        if audioURL == nil {
         if let audioPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "testaudio", ofType: "mp3") {
            let tempAudioURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath)
            audioPlayer = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: tempAudioURL)


            }
        } else {
            audioPlayer = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: audioURL!)



        }

            //check if our audio fille exist? and set it to the proerty audioPath
         audioPlayer?.prepareToPlay()



     //create audio player, make sure it not nil and if its not the prepare to play, then play






            }

    @IBAction func PlayPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        audioPlayer?.play()
    }

    @IBAction func Pausedpressed(_ sender: Any) {
        audioPlayer?.pause()
    }

    @IBAction func Stop(_ sender: Any) {
        audioPlayer?.stop()
        audioPlayer?.currentTime = 0
    }

    @IBAction func Record(_ sender: Any) {
        if let recorder = audioRecorder {
            if !recorder.isRecording {
               recorder.record()

            }

        }

    }



    @IBAction func StopRecord(_ sender: Any) {
      if let recorder = audioRecorder {
        if recorder.isRecording {
            recorder.stop()
            playerSetup(audioURL: recorder.url)


               }
            }
        }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Yes , You need to add Permission in `info.plist`**

- Go to `info.plist` of your project
- Add `Privacy - Microphone Usage Description`  and set it's Value `YES`(true)

[image]

After Setting , when you'll start recording in your app for the first time it will ask for permission , `Allow` that and you're all set !

Comment: If it worked for you ,then humbly approve the answer to support , Buddy !

Comment: I tried but it says "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."